# how to obtain selected values from a rich:orderingList?

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces

I'm using Richfaces 4, and trying to obtain the selected items in a rich:orderingList. I want these so that I can remove them from the list at the push of a "Remove" button. So for I have this:

```
<rich:orderingList id="categoriesList" listHeight="100px"
    listWidth="300px" value="#{selectionBean.availableCategories}"
    selection="${selectionBean.selectedCategories}"
    valueChangeListener="#{selectionBean.takeSelection}" >
    <a4j:ajax event="click" render="categoriesList" execute="@this" />
</rich:orderingList>
```

And the function in the @ViewScoped backing bean, which I adapted from here https://community.jboss.org/message/561295:

```
private List<String> availableCategories;

private List<String> selectedCategories;

...............................

public void takeSelection(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {
    System.out.println("ABE In takeSelection...");

    System.out.println(" Trying to find component with offering elements...");
    UIComponent component = event.getComponent();
    System.out.println(" Found: " + (component == null ? "<null>" : (component.getClass().getName() + " - " + component.getId())));
    if(component != null) {
        System.out.println( " Component that fired the event: " + component.getClass().getSimpleName() + " - " + component.getId());
        UIOrderingList orderingList = (UIOrderingList) component;

        System.out.println(" selectedCategories are "+ selectedCategories);
    }
    System.out.println(type + " Leaving takeSelection");
}
```

The problem is that when I click on the list to select an item, although I see that an Ajax request is sent, the selectedCategories list is not updated, and also the takeSelection method is not called.

Answer (score 0):

A few questions in order to better understand your problem.

What's the purpose of:

```
<a4j:ajax event="click" render="categoriesList" execute="@this" />
```

Why render the orderingList at **each** click since it's suppose to be modified only when clicking on the "remove" button?

Why does:

```
selection="${selectionBean.selectedCategories}"
```

starts with a "$" symbol instead of a "#"? (should not be blocking).

Finally, I can't find a "selection" attribute on the  component. See [VDL](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_X/vdldoc/rich/orderingList.html). Are you sure about the syntax?

Regards

Comment: 1. You are right, the render is not necessary, but I don't think it changes the problem.

2. Oops, it's a typo, should be "#"

3. The "selection" attribute was there, at least in 3.3, as seen here: http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/rich_orderingList.html#d0e38485. Maybe they took it out for version 4, although I think it was supposed to be unchanged between the two versions: https://community.jboss.org/wiki/RichFacesMigrationGuide33x-4xMigration-ComponentsMigration-RichInputComponents

Comment: I think the "selection" attribute has really be removed from 3.3 to 4.x. So the best way is to create an issue on RichFaces JIRA and ask for an enhancement on the rich:orderingList component in order to support "selection" again. Don't hesitate to post a link to the issue once created in order for people to vote for it.

Comment: I'm also suffer from this issue after migrate to richfaces 4.x, hope to get any kind of solutions...

Comment: I couldn't find any JIRA entry for it, so I created one: [RF-13662](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RF-13662). Please vote for it!